# Bellman-Ford algorithm for positive circuits

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I am working on a project with directed graphs where the weight of the edges all depend on a variable x.
I'm trying to find the minimum value of x such that my graph does not contain any circuit of positive weight.

My question is -and it is probably pretty stupid but I don't see how- :
How can I use a modified Bellman-Ford to check for the presence of positive circuits instead of negative circuits ?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do the dependencies look like? If B--F with binary search is too slow for you, there may be a better algorithm.

Comment: Well, not sure what you mean but the weight of each edge depend on x and on other values (fixed) coming from the two vertices that it connects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use a modified Bellman-Ford to check for the presence of
>   positive circuits instead of negative circuits ?

Change all the weights to their negative value:

```
w'(u,v) = -w(u,v)
```

And then simply run regular BF.

You can run a binary search on that value `x` to find the minimal value that is needed for a negative cycle, for example, in `O(logx)` invokations of BF.

---

A more efficient solution to find the minimal weight of edge `(u,v)` needed to make a negative cycle, is to remove that edge, find the shortest path from `v` to `u`.

Now, you can tell what should be the weight of the edge to get a cycle of weight 0, (`-d(v,u)`), anything more than that - you have a positive cycle, less - negative cycle.

Comment: Thanks ! I was planning to use a binary search to find x, I was just wondering how to be sure that my graph does not contain a positive cycle.
This should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find shortest paths and do not want to use negative edges, you can use Dijkstra Algorithm which is nearly similar to Bellman-Ford.

However, if you want to just access the edges with possibly low weights, you can look "Prim's Algorithm" or "Kruskall Algorithm", these are using for find "Minimum Spanning Tree(MST)" for graphs.

[Dijkstra Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)

[Prim's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)

[Kruskal's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm)